# jQuery datepicker default date with current month and day and the year 2006

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have some jquery code here for my datepicker

```
$birth.datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
    $gender.focus();
},
    yearRange: '1950:2006',
    changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,           
showOtherMonths: true,          
selectOtherMonths: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

I am trying to set a `defaultDate` for my datepicker for the date to be 2006-currentMonth-currentDay

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var date = new Date();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker(
        {defaultDate: date.getDay()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/2006'});
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9HwAP/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object and set the year to 2006, and pass it as a defaultDate parameter to the datepicker

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2006);

$birth.datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
    $gender.focus();
},
    yearRange: '1950:2006',
    changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,           
showOtherMonths: true,          
selectOtherMonths: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
defaultDate: d
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a date object using `new Date()`.  Then gather the current month and the current date, using  the date methods `getMonth()` and `getDate()`.

Then in the datepicker function, use the `setDate` method to assign the default date by concatenating the hardcoded year (2006) with the current month and date.

**Note:** For the month I increased it by 1, since getMonth() goes from 0-11 (Jan-Dec) and the jQuery datepicker goes from 1-12 for Jan-Dec

**HTML:**

```
<label for="datepicker">Date: </label><input id="datepicker" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var todaysDate = new Date(),
    month = todaysDate.getMonth() + 1,
    date = todaysDate.getDate();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    })
    .datepicker('setDate', '2006' + '-' + month + '-' + date);
})
```

See the example of it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tuant/RvHa8/